# Dog developed dewlap and died

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, death, strays

A street puppy (about 8 months old) died in my vicinity. Cause of death was unknown, but following symptoms were visible in his body:

1. He developed a dewlap (major symptom).
2. It seemed that he had congestion in his throat, he coughed a lot.
3. He refused to consume anything, water too. He became quiet.

It seemed that he wanted to eat, he would come and sniff the eatable, but didn't eat.

There were no other visible symptoms in his body. He was healthy. It was winter and in 4 days he died. His body was a little swollen after he died.

What could be the reason for the dewlap he developed and his death?

Answer (score 4):

There could be a few things that caused the dewlap to form.  From [this source](http://www.dailydogdiscoveries.com/tag/dog-dewlap/), some include:

- Hyperthyroidism
- Enlarged lymph glands
- Fluids leaking out of blood vessels

The source also states that injuries could cause a kind of "knot" to form under the skin in this area which may end up being an abscess or seroma (a collection of fluid under the skin).

Since the dog didn't want to eat, I would assume that whatever caused it was also causing pain.  Medically, something was probably wrong. Of course, certain breeds of dogs have natural dewlaps, but since you said it formed, it doesn't sound like this is one of those dogs.

Answer (score 1):

A dewlap (excessive skin or skin flapping around the throat) can also be caused by an injury such as a dog fight or snake bite or imbedded collar, etc... that then becomes infected thus causing a fluid build up. The infection could've spread to bloodstream, kidneys, brain and/or spine threatening the dog's life and eating habits. If he was sick due to infection, this could've killed him by starvation, fever, or by the infection itself.